# rxjs mapTo operator: evaluate the return value at run time

Tags: rxjs

```
  function c() {
     return Math.random();
  }

  source$.pipe(
    map(a => c())
  ).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

Say there's a simple code like above. What I tried was logging the value when the source stream emits something but obviously, the value I log has nothing to do with the value from the source stream. So it got me considering using `mapTo` operator like this:

```
  function c() {
   return Math.random();
  }

  source$.pipe(
    mapTo(c())
  ).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

But as you may guess, the value is always the same. More accurately speaking, it stays as the first value which is not what I want.

So my point is, I want the evaluation to be executed each time the source emits a value which I don't use at the evaluation. I can get it working like the first code by using `map` operator but it just doesn't seem right to use `map` when I don't use the value from the source stream. Is it okay to use `map` like this? Or is there any workaround for this kind of matter using `mapTo` or something else? Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Does your use case really involve a random number? Or is it some other form of external state? External state is best avoided, so I get the feeling there might be more to your question.

Comment: @cartant It's not involved with a random number but I want to return a value which needs to evaluated each time but nothing to do with the value from the source stream

Comment: I think what you're doing with `map` is fine. If you don't need the value that comes from the source Observable you can make it more obvious by not including it in the parameters at all `map(() => c())`.

Comment: Shorter than mapTo : `source$.pipe(map(c))`

Comment: @martin Gotcha! Thanks.

Comment: @ibenjelloun I didn't know that syntax! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official definition](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mapTo), `mapTo` emits the **given constant value** on the output Observable every time the source Observable emits a value.

Therefore the behavior you described is the expected one. The first evaluation from `Math.random()` is kept and emitted for every time.

There seems nothing wrong to use `map` here to get the random values as you expect.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but just can't help feeling wrong/awkward about not using the value from the source stream when using `map` operator.

Comment: Well, every project is unique so as every use-case. If you want to emit a random value when the source emits without caring the source value, then using map may be the way.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ignoring the value of the source at all. It's also not exotic – it happens quite a bit. Observables have a data and a time component and ignoring the parameter simply means you're only interested in the time component. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thanks for the insight!